# Xcode - Repairing 'Could not load NIB in bundle' error

Tags: objective-c

New Objective C programmer here and this is one of my first applications so any help would be highly appreciated.

I am trying to navigate from one TableView to another with this application, but I get a 'Could not load NIB in bundle' error. I have researched solutions and tried to add the target membership through build phases, but nothing works. So I am assuming something is wrong with my code. Would anyone mind looking at it and telling me what I can do to fix it? I added a github link below to make it easier to see.

https://github.com/zamirly/STSneakers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should made something like this.
Instead of

```
    self.details = [[STSneakerBrandDetailTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"STSneakerBrandDetailTableViewController" bundle:nil];
```

insert next line:

```
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];
    self.details = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"STSneakerBrandDTVC"];
```

Than in main.storyboard select STSneakerBrandDetailTableViewController and write STSneakerBrandDTVC in Stryboard ID field.

Comment: Hi @stosha thank you that really helped and it works. Just another question in case you don't mind helping out. When I click on one of the brands and it transfers me to the next table, everything works fine, but if I press the 'back' navigation button and then click on another brand, it brings me back to the brand I originally pressed. Do you know why? thanks

Comment: Hi @Zambot unfortunately I can't repead your steps because your base is empty.

Comment: @Zambo, try replace property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *uniqueBrand; to property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *uniqueBrand; and move line self.versionInfo = [[STSneakerDatabaseVersionNames database] getAllVersionNames:_uniqueBrand]; to viewWillAppear

Comment: @Zambo sorry for the delay. I went to office... :) you should add next code to the STSneakerBrandDetailTableViewController: - (void) setVersionInfo:(NSArray *)versionInfo
{
    _versionInfo = versionInfo;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}